# how to open RSS feed url in android?

Tags: android, webview

i want to open RSS feed URL like [yahoo](http://news.yahoo.com/rss/) in android WebView.

> i used webView.loadUrl(urlString) method.if i use this,a page having full of html data with   >html,img...tags opens.its not opening the original webpage. how to open that URL in webView   >properly as opened in normal browsers like safari,IE?

Comment: How would the WebView load an RSS feed? It's an XML file, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Also look at the original documentation tutorial here. Make sure you have everything correct.

[Hello Webview](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.i used that line already.normal web pages are opening properly. RSS feed urls not opening.:(

Comment: Well are you using the correct rss url? The link you provided above is actually meant to be parsed from the looks of it.

Comment: My intention is to open that specific url in android WebView in the same way as it opens in traditional browsers like iE,safari,Mozilla...Please browse that URL in android browser to understand the problem.

Comment: without parsing is it possible to display the page?